# AutocompleteTextView with room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have a Room db and have created a model and viewModel. I was wondering how to make an autocompletetextview work with the database data and the viewmodel to filter the customer list as the user types

ViewModel

```
class CustomerVM : ViewModel() {
    private val customers: MutableLiveData<List<Customer>> by lazy {
        loadCustomers()
    }

    fun getCustomers(): LiveData<List<Customer>> {
        return customers
    }

    private fun loadCustomers() : MutableLiveData<List<Customer>> {
        return DataModel.getInstance().roomDb.CustomerDao().getAllCustomers() as MutableLiveData<List<Customer>>
    }
}
```

Comment: Do this. `val adapter = AutocompleteArrayAdapter(context!!, R.layout.location_drop_down_autocomplete, yourListOfCustomers)
        yourAutoComplete.setAdapter(adapter)`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you want to have as entries of your autocomplete text view the data that you have in the internal DB.

To do that i create my custom ViewModel with allStudentsData, repository an listen from activity

1. Repository Class
   A repository that is listening directly from DB

   `val allStudents: LiveData<List<Student>> = studentDao.getAll()`
2. ViewModel Class

```
   init {
        val studentsDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application,viewModelScope).studentsDao()
        studentRepository = StudentRepository(studentsDao)
        allStudents = studentRepository.allStudents
    }
```

3. Activity Class

```
    private lateinit var studentViewModel: StudentViewModel

    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        studentViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(StudentViewModel::class.java)
        studentViewModel.allStudents.observe(this, Observer { students ->
            // Update the cached copy of the students in the adapter.
            students?.let {
                val arr = mutableListOf<String>()

                for (value in it) {
                    arr.add(value.name)
                }
                val adapter: ArrayAdapter<String> =
                    ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, arr)
                names.setAdapter(adapter)
            }
        })
    }
```

In the activity we have a viewModel variable that observe the data that is change when new record is insert in DB.
When we have new data Observer {} is called, so with the new list of students we create a mutable list, we add all students and we set the adapter

By doing this, when data change in DB

**DB** ====> **Repository** ====> **ViewModel** ====> **Activity**

Answer (score -1):

```
 step 1:create custom autocomplete text view

     example:https://spapas.github.io/2019/04/05/android-custom-filter-adapter/

 step2:get data from room dp

       @Query("SELECT * FROM Gender WHERE name == :name")
       fun getGenderByName(name: String): List<Gender>

 step3:update this data to  custom autocomplete adapter
```